# Different Permissions for different files / folders with bindfs

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, permissions, file-permissions

I'm following this guide: [link](http://blog.netgusto.com/solving-web-file-permissions-problem-once-and-for-all/) on how to use bindfs. I have a question however. The guide only mentions broadsweep permissions for all files, however if I want seperate permissions (644 for files, and 755 for folders), how would I go by doing this with bindfs?

Answer (score 2):

To make the standard permissions of 0755 for directories and 0644 for files replace the permissions part for the script in /etc/fstab from:

create-with-perms=0770

to:

create-with-perms=god=rx:ud=rwx:gof=r:uf=rw

Comment: @Issac Pak  - Its been a few years but your answer is the only one where i could see the issue of file / directory permissions being addressed. Could you kindly elaborate on your answer better ( each flag ) and how its used in /etc/fstab  in perms syntax ( perms=0770 ). If you use perms syntax, do we need create-with-perms ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `create-with-perms=0644:a+X` to the fstab entry.